# How do I run a c file with arguments like in GitHub's terminal?

Tags: c, bash, visual-studio-code

I am switching from a GitHub workspace to VS code.

I still have to make `C` code with command line arguments. The command would look something like `./code input output`

How do I do this when I need to be able to keep switching both arguments regularly?

Comment: use terminal in VS

Comment: So, you compile your program, and then pass the argument to the executable, when invoking it from the command line. Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to go "raw", you can use"int argc, char **argv", but if you want an easy solution, you can chose betwen use the native lib getopt, wich i consider hard, or use an "more high level lib", like C-Cli-Entry, these is my lib, and I dont know if its consider self promotion, but any way:

first:
Go to the repo:
https://github.com/OUIsolutions/C-Cli-Entry

Second:
Download the entire ""CliEntry.h" file to your project

Third:
Now you can retrive any argv flags and args , in these case, I am simulating getting the output flag argument, acessed by:  "./program -o file.txt":

```c
#include "CliEntry.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    CliNamespace cli = newCliNamespace();


    CliEntry *entry = newCliEntry(argc,argv);
    //get the flag
    CliFlag *output_flag = cli.entry.get_flag(entry,"o | out | output",CLI_NOT_CASE_SENSITIVE);
   
    //verify if exist
    if(output_flag->exist == false){
        printf("you didint passed the output\n");
        cli.entry.free(entry);
        return 1;
    }
    //verifying the size
    if(output_flag->size == 0){
        printf("the output flag its empty\n");
        cli.entry.free(entry);
        return 1;
    }
    int position = 0;
    char *output_content = cli.flag.get_str(output_flag,position,CLI_CASE_SENSITIVE);
    printf("content of output:%s\n",output_content);

    //do stuff here 

    cli.entry.free(entry);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If we're into libraries, you can have a look at [the CLI module in the facil.io C STL library](https://github.com/facil-io/cstl/blob/85958a356490902df76e6cd03e50b561db3ef633/fio-stl/005%20cli.md)... shameless plug or a response?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code is not integrated with a compiler so you won't be able to pass arguments in an easy way.

You can embark yourself in a quest of installing the compiler following the instructions here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp .

Keep in mind that installing a compiler is not easy if you are a beginner.

An easier way would be to install Visual Studio Community and use a `C++ Console App` template for creating a project. Then , from Visual Studio you can add arguments like this: `Debug->Debug Properties->Configuration->Debugging->Command Line Arguments` .

Answer (score -1):

You will have to compile the program.

The command line interface (CLI) options are passed to the function `main`:

```c
int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
 // ...
}
```

At which point you would test the CLI argument  in `argv` for what you need.

i.e. (didn't test this, as I'm writing directly to the web):

```c
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
  {
    printf("CLI option %d: %s", argv[i]);
  }

  if(argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "missing input / output arguments.");
    exit(-1);
  }

  const char * input = argv[1];
  const char * output = argv[2];

  // ... 
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, the code needs to be compiled before you can run it.

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: @0___________ - the question was how to accept command line arguments in C. How does this not answer the question?

Comment: Because he asks how to pass arguments to the program in VScode, not how to use them in C program

Comment: @0___________ - does he? that's not how I understood the question at all. But I guess, if my answer doesn't help OP they don't have to upvote or anything... or do you think I should be panelized for trying to help?